# Get all authorized GoogleSignInAccount's - Drive REST API

Tags: android, google-api, google-drive-api, google-signin, google-drive-android-api

What I'm trying to do is actually to authorize multiple google accounts and then construct multiple [Drive](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/java/latest/) objects to be able to make file system operations on behalf of both authorized users simultaneously. The problem is that [GoogleSignInClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInClient) allows to log in only with one user at once and the [GoogleSignIn](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignIn) queries only for the last logged in account ([getLastSignedInAccount](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignIn.html#getLastSignedInAccount(android.content.Context))) and there is no way to obtain all the authorized accounts, means I can only manage one Drive connection at a time. Is there a way to give a user an option to connect all his accounts at once?

What I'm trying to achieve is similar to a native Android file picker app which has all the available drive accounts simultaneously:
[image]

What I have now is a working sample for only one account:

```
private fun requestSignIn() {

        val signInOptions = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .requestScopes(Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE))
                .build()

        client = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, signInOptions)

        // The result of the sign-in Intent is handled in onActivityResult.
        startActivityForResult(client?.signInIntent, REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        when (requestCode) {
            REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN -> {
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                    handleSignInResult(data)
                }
            }
            else -> super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        }
    }

    private fun handleSignInResult(data: Intent) {
        GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    val credential =
                            GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE))
                    credential.selectedAccount = it.account

                    val googleDriveService = Drive.Builder(
                            AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                            GsonFactory(),
                            credential)
                            .setApplicationName("CCFS")
                            .build()

                    // use drive service for a specific account
                }
                .addOnFailureListener {
                    Log.e("QWER", "Unable to sign in.", it)
                }
    }
```

Now, to connect another user, i must logout the previous one and login with the new one. No way to maintain two logged in users.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/android/deprecation

Comment: And...? Im using the Drive rest api java wrapper and not the android drive sdk.. Look at the mentioned objects.

Comment: then you've tagged the question wrongfully with `google-drive-android-api`, which coincidentally is that one deprecated library - which would have permitted to access to the id token. when using the `GoogleSignInClient`, there might be no way to maintain several `oAuth2` flows.

Comment: The tag intended to interest people who dealt with drive SDK in general and maybe done something similar to my question on android. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

you'd need to use class [GoogleCredential](http://%20https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-java-client/releases/1.25.0/javadoc/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredential.html) in order to support several `oAuth2` flows:

> Thread-safe Google-specific implementation of the OAuth 2.0 helper for accessing protected resources using an access token, as well as optionally refreshing the access token when it expires using a refresh token.
>   There are three modes supported: access token only, refresh token flow, and service account flow (with or without impersonating a user).

the `GoogleSignInClient` could in best case be used to initially get the email address.

the `AccountManager` could be used to keep the tokens of alternate Google accounts.

because otherwise, the obtained token is saved along with the chosen Google account

(only an assumption, because of closed source - but based upon the behavior).

Comment: Actually, I'm using GoogleCredential, see my updated question.